# Get data after click with Selenium (Python 3)

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape a page with simple information.

I'm using *BeautifulSoup* to scrape the data. But in the page there's a button that hides the email information. So I tried *Selenium* to chick and then with *BeautifulSoup* I scrape the data. But I don't really know how to do it.

I did:

```
import requests, time, re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

url = "https://acukwik.com/Basic-Info/UUBP/RUSAERO"

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)

while True:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html5lib')
    divEmail = soup.find('div', text=re.compile('Email'))
    try:
        driver.find_elements_by_class_name('ghEmail').click()
        time.sleep(3)
        email = divEmail.findNext('a')['href']
        print(email)
    except:
        break

driver.quit()
```

What happens is that a Chrome page opens in the given url but nothing happens. It just opens and closes. I don't see the button change.

What am I doing wrong? And how to get that data? And can I do it just with *BeautifulSoup*?

Comment: Did you try this get call? https://acukwik.com/desktopmodules/Services/api/FunctionsWS/GetGHEmail?GROUND_HANDLER_ID=19&Service_Type_ID=10

Answer (score 1):

ypou are using find_elements which returns alist and you are trying to click a list  so it fails always, so you can change find_elements_by_class to find_element_by_class.

Also you can use the locator: "//div[contains(text(),'Email')]/../div[2]/a"

to get tthe email after the click

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
chrome_options.add_argument("window-size=1920,1080")
#chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox") # linux only
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")

url = "https://acukwik.com/Basic-Info/UUBP/RUSAERO"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
driver.get(url)
divEmail = driver.find_element_by_class_name('ghEmail').click()

time.sleep(1)

email = driver.find_element_by_xpath(
    "//div[contains(text(),'Email')]/../div[2]/a")
print(email.text)
driver.quit()
```

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what i need!
A small question: how can I change to not pop-open a chrome page?

Comment: use options.add_arguments headless

Answer (score 1):

You are getting soup before clicking on the `show mail` button. You need to click on button first and then get the page source.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time, re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

driver=webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://acukwik.com/Basic-Info/UUBP/RUSAERO")
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.ghEmail"))).click()
time.sleep(1)
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html5lib')
divEmail = soup.find('div', text=re.compile('Email'))
email = divEmail.findNext('a')['href']
print(email)
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this code to get Email:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

...
driver.find_element_by_class_name('ghEmail').click()
email = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//a[starts-with(@href, "mailto:")]'))).text
```